# Shrinking a smallmatrix in a subscript

Tags: fontsize

In mathmode, the code

```
\mathrm{h}_{
\begin{smallmatrix}X\\
\downarrow\\ S
\end{smallmatrix}}
```

Yields the output below. Wrapping the `smallmatrix` with a `\scriptscriptstyle` has no effect on the output. How can I make the `smallmatrix` smaller in the subscript?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now you just have to get glasses.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,graphicx}
\begin{document}
$
\mathrm{h}_{\scalebox{.5}{$
\begin{smallmatrix}X\\
\downarrow\\ S
\end{smallmatrix}$}}
$
\end{document}
```

[image]

And an alternative using a TABstack, which has the advantage of employing `\scriptscriptstyle` fonts that are more readable at small sizes:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabstackengine,graphicx}
\TABstackMathstyle{\scriptscriptstyle}
\TABstackMath
\setstackgap{S}{.5pt}
\begin{document}
$
\mathrm{h}_{\scalebox{.8}{\tabbedShortstack{X\\ \downarrow\\ S}}}
$
\end{document}
```

[image]

By the way, changing the `\tabbedShortstack` to a `\tabbedShortunderstack` results in moving the script a bit lower:

[image]